# Spotify iOS SDK - SPTAudioStreamingDelegate protocol functions not being called?

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I'm working on a simple app that allows a user to sign in with his/her spotify account and then plays a song after user authentication. I tried following the spotify-provided tutorial, but it's fairly outdated. When I run the app and press the "log in" button, it links to the spotify authentication URL and verifies my account. However, when it redirects to my app, no music playing. The only thing that is printed to the console is the print statement "login successful" from viewDidLoad.

I've added the spotify frameworks, linked the libraries, and created a bridging header file (the SDK is written in OBJ-C).

**ViewDidLoad**

[image: ViewDidLoad]

**audioStreamingDidLogin**

[image: audioStreamingDidLogin]

This delegate function is never called and the "logged in" and "playing" print statements are never printed to the console.

I'm wondering if there's something wrong with the way I set up the delegate because it seems that its not being recognized.

**Delegate Setup**

[image: Delegate Setup]

Here is what I've added in the app delegate:

**App Delegate**

[image: App Delegate]

**App Delegate**

[image: App Delegate]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out ? Also, were you logging in using a free account or a premium subscription ?

Comment: did you get any solution for the same?